# Is Lumia-920 and Windows Phone 8 the same thing?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

Is the lumia-920 the same thing as Windows phone 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Lumia 920 is a Nokia phone running the Windows Phone 8 operating system. So you can call the Lumia 920 a Windows Phone 8 phone, but you cannot call Windows Phone 8 a Lumia 920 phone.

So far Nokia, Samsung, Huawei and HTC [have announced](http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/windows-phone-8-release-date-and-latest-details-1065086) that the will be releasing WP8 devices.

Comment: Are\Will-be there any other phones running Windows 8?

Comment: Nokia, Samsung, Huawei and HTC will be releasing various models.

Answer (score 1):

[Nokia Lumia 920](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/phones/phone/lumia920/) (AKA Lumia 920) is a phone. [Windows Phone 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_8) (AKA WP8) is the operating system held of Lumia 920. [This](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/phones/lumia/) link will give you more information on what Lumia Phones are available and which ones hold WP8.